# Using cUrl to login my website

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am trying to login to my A site from my B site. So I simulate a login form using curl and I expect to redirect to my A site's main member page. But instead my B site url remain on my address bar and my browser shows my Site A login page. I am new to curl. Thank you for reading.

```
$cc = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
    return curl_exec($cc);
    curl_close($cc);
    //echo $result;
    //exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `curl` your *server* makes a request to A and receives a response. It has nothing to do with the client.

```
                 1) request         2) request (curl)
                   --->               --->
Client (browser)           Server B          Server A
                   <---               <---
                 4) response        3) response
```

If you want to tell the client something or redirect him, you have to do so in *your* response to the client. `curl` won't do anything like this. For example, use `header('Location: http://a.com')` to redirect the client in step 4.